# 3 programmatically created UIButtons - how to go between 3 UIViewControllers using those buttons with Storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

Playing around with some Objective-C (well, iOS) and have done the following... loaded some `UIButtons` programmatically into a `UIScrollView`. That works well. Though I've always just connected `UIViewControllers` together using control-click and drag. Now I've created buttons programmatically, I have no idea how to go from one view controller to another in a `Storyboard` because there is nothing to drag from!

I'm not really sure what code to post as such, because I haven't done anything that /nearly/ works or doesn't work as such. I get how to do it with `XIBs`. But I suppose the question is : 3 `UIButtons` have been created programmatically and I have 3 `UIViewControllers`. How do I access those `ViewControllers` using my `UIButtons`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Interface builder view control click and drag from the viewcontroller icon under the first view controller, to the middle of the second view controller. A segue will be created, selected the appropriate type.

[image: Creating the segue]

Now select the segue and in the inspector give it a unique identifier (say 'myNewSegue').

[image: Setting identifier]

Now in your first viewcontroller you can create a method that has the following code:

```
-(void)myButtonAction:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myNewSegue" sender:self];
}
```

And add this method as a target action to your button:

```
[myButton addTarget:self
             action:@selector(myButtonAction:)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];]
```

Comment: Love you. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

A segue doesn't *have* to have a button at the leading end of it; you can instead draw it from an entire view controller to another. You can also give a segue an *identifier*, a string that's used as a name for that segue. Once you've done that, you can programmatically trigger that segue by calling `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`.

To actually call `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`, though, you'll need to connect the button to a target and action. If you've never done that, read the *Event Handling Guide for iOS* in your documentation.